# Why does the getX() getY() of MouseEvent seem to offset from the real coordinate?

Tags: java, swing

I have a `JPanel` embedded inside a `JFrame`. `JPanel` is added at `CENTER` of `BorderLayout`. I am using the following code to draw on it but the `MouseEvent`'s `getX()` and `getY()` seem to offset the real coordinate. Why?

The relevant code is:-

```
private Image backBuffer = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());

public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    //System.out.println("Canvas.mouseDragged()");
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) backBuffer.getGraphics();
    int x = e.getX(), y = e.getY();
    if(lastCoord == null) {
        g2d.drawRect(x, y, 0, 0);
    } else {
        g2d.drawLine(lastCoord[0], lastCoord[1], x, y);
    }
    lastCoord = new Integer[]{x, y};
    repaint();
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D graphics2D = (Graphics2D) g;
    graphics2D.setColor(Color.black);
    graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    graphics2D.drawImage(backBuffer, 0, 0, null);
}
```

[image: What I mean by offset]

Comment: My guess the X and Y returned by MouseEvent here is not relative to the Graphics2D object's coordinate system. Try using getXOnScreen() and getYOnScreen() and see if that fixes it up.

Comment: what object is the mouse listener installed on?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Maybe you've added your mouse listener to the JFrame (and not to the panel) so getX and getY values are relative to the JFrame. Then the offsets are the JFrame borders and upper title bar.